# ssh rsa key no longer works for one account

Tags: ssh, rsa

I can no longer use public keys on one account I have on a remote system. It worked fine for a while, but it doesn't seem to now(I still have to input my password each time I login). It started one day when I had several terminals remotely logged into my account(scp and ssh) from the same computer (also I remember I changed the permissions on my home directory that day, and at one point really messed them up, I feel that may have something to do with it).

when I run ssh -v:

```
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/bobak/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/bobak/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/bobak/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.3 pat OpenSSH_4*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.2
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/bobak/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/bobak/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/bobak/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/bobak/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

any ideas as to what happened? There are other accounts on the computer which still work with RSA keys, but just not mine. I have tried to recreate the key, I have even gone as far as deleting my authorized keys file and remaking it, as well as trying from different computers.

Comment: Are the permissions on the files and upstream directories set correctly?

Comment: What are the permission of your .ssh directory and its content on the computer where you have to login by password ? Give the output of thess commands: ls -ld $HOME/.ssh and ls -Rl $HOME/.ssh

Comment: home/.ssh/ is drwxr-xr-x


home/.ssh/authorized_keys is -rwx------

Comment: I'm encountering a similar problem: on the same system, I use one RSA key to login to one account, but trying to set up public-private key auto-login with other accounts doesn't work. I'm on: `ssh -v OpenSSH_5.2p1, OpenSSL 0.9.7l 28 Sep 2006` for my local laptop. I'm also using RSA like you are.

Comment: @slubman for the account that works my file permissions are: `drwx------  2 mravery pg2054728 4.0K May 16 16:31 ./` and `-rw-------  1 mravery pg2054728 1.2K Aug  7  2010 authorized_keys` For the one that doesn't work: `drwx------  2 uclaan pg2054728 4.0K May 16 16:19 ./` and `-rw-------  1 uclaan pg2054728  403 May 16 16:19 authorized_keys`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue. The problem I was having was a permissions issue. My remote server is with Dreamhost so they may have configured the server set up so that public/private keys work like this. This is what I did, YMMV:

1. *Changed the permissions in the home folder of each of my accounts that this weren't working to 751.* I'm assuming that your setup needs at least this if not stronger. This worked for me... but I also did these other steps which you can try.
2. *Changed the permissions of everything in .ssh to 600.*
3. *Switched to using a new key with DSA instead of RSA.* This was overkill but I encrypted the private key so now it asks for a password before I can use the private key. This is just a security measure. Mac OS X lets me save the password so that this happens transparently (ie. I don't have to type in my password per se).

Comment: DSA fixed it, but I still don't know what the problem was/is with RSA. Really odd, thanks for the patch though.